# Get $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] in PHP5 running on Windows

Tags: php, windows

It does not seem as simple. I use this popular function to get page full URL:

```
private function getBaseUrl() {
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
        $pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

My PHP5 is on Windows server! That is why **$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]** is empty. I used this workaround for Windows:

```
function fixRequestURI() {
    if(!isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
        $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];
        if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] .= '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        }
    }
}
```

However, it kinda works. My full URL is:

```
http://www.domain.com/web/en/contact/
```

Strangely, I get this as a result of my functions above:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory1/web/en/contact/index.php?go=3
```

This, so called, "directory1" is my physical directory to which domain.com is mapped. I understand the implications but... how would I get my full URL easily without any fixes, adjustments, etc. just like in JavaScript using **document.location.href**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question: this worked for me:

```
function getFullUrl() {     
    $pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
        $pageURL .= "://";          
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];
    } else {
        $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL'];//$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] blank
    }
    return $pageURL;
}
```

Please send me any thoughts if it can ever fail in any special circumstances.

Comment: It looks like the fact that my www.domain.com, when pointed to /directory1/, somehow does not tell $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] or $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] about the mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?
function getUrl(){
    $http = 'http' . (@$_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 's' : '');
    $query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? "?$_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]" : '';
    return "$http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]$query";
}
```

It won't catch the anchors though (after the hash `#` tag)

Comment: I get the same: http://www.domain.com/directory1/web/en/contact/index.php?go=3 from this URL http://www.domain.com/web/en/contact/index.php?go=3

Comment: Output `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` separately. Which one contains the directory1?

Comment: $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] does.

Comment: What about `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`?

Comment: script name is OK (domain.com) but uri is blank however the fix above sets it to whatever $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] produces.

Comment: sorry I meant script name contains 'directory1'